# Enabling two sided material for 3D mesh files in Cocos2D-X

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am developing a 3D game with **Cocos2D-X**. I have converted .fbx mesh file into .c3b and .c3t file format using fbx-conv tool. I have imported these files into 3D scene and they are displayed properly along with the materials. I want these mesh files to be **two sided**. I did research but could not find helpful resources. Also, there is no **Material Editor** (present in UE4 and Unity3D) available in Cocos2D-X through which I can enable two sided property. How should I implement **two sided mesh files** in Cocos2D-X?

I’d appreciate any suggestions on this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Isn't two-sided material (backface culling off) an attribute of the renderer and only available globally?  If so it's one of settings available via `glEnable()`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes, two-sided material(backface culling off) is an attribute of the renderer. I tried using glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE) command in my source file "HelloWorld.cpp" in Cocos2D-X. But it has no effect. Which files possibly I need to modify and what are the required modifications in Cocos2D-X project?

Comment: That's more likely to be `glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);` as you don't want face culling.

Comment: I tried both enabling and disabling face culling but still not able to get the desired output.

Comment: To be honest I don't know.  I would try the cocos2d-x forums or /r/gamedev.

Comment: OK. Thank you. I have posted question on Cocos2D-X forum.